# What is the best way to work privately on pypi released package within Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a Python package that is released in pypi and can be installed via `pip install`.

I want to do some minor changes in that package that are only of use for me in my Pycharm project A. I expect that these changes will be quite frequent, so I want to be able to do these changes on the fly.

I know that I can work with a local copy of that project / package by doing the following steps:

1. perform a `git clone`
2. use that code as a separate Pycharm project B
3. in my own project A, I write:

   ```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/second_pycharm_project')

    import project_name
   ```

Now I can do code changes in the Pycharm project B and executing project A just reflects that correctly.

Nevertheless, I have some constraints:

1. Variable / code lookup within Pycharm is not possible this way.
2. Setting a breakpoint in project B has to be done within project A and seems to work only while entering the code of B during debugging.

My question is:

Is there any other (better) way to use another project within Pycharm?

(I thought of changing the code that gets copied by `pip install` in my virtual environment directly, but this seems very unclean and dangerous to me, in case my changes get accidentally overwritten by `pip install`)

Comment: What about a clone then `pip install -E` of B on A’s virtualenv?  That’s a local editable install and puts B in A sys.path.  Branch B so you can do your edits wo impact to git origin. Don’t use pycharm so not sure how that works w its projects but it’s a lot more Pythonic than hardcoding injection into sys.path

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I am with you, that this makes it more Pythonic as compared to the hardcoding injection. But still my two topics remain.

Comment: So pycharm does not pick up the module even though it is now on sys.path?  Cant help you there, I already struggle w sublime projects.  Although... is there an *add directory to project* functionality in pycharm?

Comment: yes, you are right. This seems already to be the solution. Very nice. That helped a lot.

Comment: Well, you can accept the answer I’ve put in if you want.  Maybe comment what the actual pycharm command is.  Wasnt sure it would work but thought it might.

Comment: Adding another directory to the actual project works this way in PyCharm: `Settings | (current) Project | Project Structure | Add Content Root`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone then `pip install -e .` of B on A’s virtualenv (do it in the directory with B’s **setup.py**). That’s a local editable install and puts B in A sys.path.

Git Branch B so you can do your local B edits wo impact to its git origin (but could still merge it later if you wish to).

Use `Settings | (current) Project | Project Structure | Add Content Root`  in Pycharm to add the other project B to your main project A.

(Make sure you keep track of local B changes because nothing here does that if you were to duplicate your work on a different machine and git clone B again).

**Remark**: it must be a small `-e` and not a big `-E`.